# How to use Silverlight SDK with WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight

as easy as it sounds,

How can I use the themes provided in SL SDk 4.0 into WPF project??

It should be easy!! Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

While Silverlight and WPF are related they are not identical. Each has namespaces, classes and methods that don't exist in the other.

Simply copying the Silverlight xaml into your WPF project and fixing the compile errors is one approach, but I wouldn't recommend it. There are differences, like Triggers for example, that have no direct equivalent.